# Is there a way to read a text file byte by byte asynchronously with POSIX threads?

Tags: c, pthreads, aio

I am trying to read and copy its contents to another file asynchronously with POSIX threads in C. Assuming a file contains "aabbcc" and i have 4 threads, how can i copy "aabbcc" to another file with threads asynchronously in C. This part has been stuck in my head for the entire day. What i have done so far is shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <aio.h>
#include <math.h> //for ceil() and floor()
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FILE_SIZE 1024 //in bytes

//>cc code.c -o code.out -lrt -lpthread
//>./code.out

char alphabets[52] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o',
                    'p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
                    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O',
                    'P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

long prepareInputFile(char* filename)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot write to input file\n");
        return;
    }
    int index;
    char str[FILE_SIZE];
    int rand_size = (rand() % 1024)+1;
for(index = 0;index < rand_size;index++) /*Generate the file with random sizes in bytes*/
{
    int num2 = (rand() % 52); /*Get a random char in char array*/
    putc(alphabets[num2],fp); /*Write that char to the file pointed to by fp*/
}
putc('\n',fp);
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
long size = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
return size;
}
//Perform main operation inside this function
void *writeToFileAsync(void *src_file, void *dest_file, 
                       void *thread, void *t_count, void *filesize)
{
    int readfd, writefd;
    struct aiocb aio_write, aio_read;
    memset(&aio_read, 0, sizeof(aio_read));
    aio_read.aio_fildes = readfd;
    aio_read.aio_nbytes = (int)filesize/(int)t_count;
    readfd = open((char *)src_file, O_RDONLY);
    if(readfd < 0)
    {
        printf("Cannot open the file for reading\n");
    }
    memset(&aio_write, 0, sizeof(aio_write));
    aio_read.aio_fildes = writefd;
    aio_read.aio_nbytes = (int)filesize/(int)t_count;
    writefd = open((void *)dest_file, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);
    if(writefd < 0)
    {
        printf("Cannot open the file for writing\n");
    }
    return;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i,threadCount;
char sourcePath[100], destPath[100];
strcpy(sourcePath,argv[1]);
if(strcmp(sourcePath, "-") == 0)
{
    getcwd(sourcePath, sizeof(sourcePath));
    strcpy(sourcePath, strcat(sourcePath, "/source.txt"));
}
else
{
    strcpy(sourcePath, strcat(sourcePath, "source.txt"));
}   
printf("Source path is: %s\n", sourcePath);
strcpy(destPath,argv[2]);
if(strcmp(destPath, "-") == 0)
{
    getcwd(destPath, sizeof(destPath));
    strcpy(destPath, strcat(destPath, "/destination.txt"));
}
else
{
    strcpy(destPath, strcat(destPath, "destination.txt"));
}
printf("Dest path is: %s\n", destPath);
threadCount = strtol(argv[3],NULL,10);
long file_size = prepareInputFile(sourcePath);
pthread_t threads[threadCount];
for(i=0;i<threadCount;i++)
{
    pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,(void *)writeToFileAsync, NULL);
}
return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It’s a bit unclear what you mean by asynchronously here (I assume “in the background”?). Also how the multiple threads would work here, copying a single file or multiple? There’s a lot of issues with this code so I would suggest making it work without threads first before trying to add them to the mix, if there even is any reason to use threads.

Comment: Threads will copy single file and yes asynchronous as in "in the background"

Comment: So multiple threads copying a single file? Why?

Comment: So far i have learned posix threads and asynchronous I/O separately and I wanted to mix them with a simple application

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that parallelizing this operation would help, as it is probably bound by I/O rather than CPU time, and copying this way will certainly not be faster than simply copying via system call.

However, if you wanted to do this, one method would be: map the input file into memory (with `mmap()` or the equivalent), create the destination buffer or memory-mapped file, divide the source and destination files into equal slices, and have each thread copy its slice of the file.  You might use `memcpy()`, but a modern compiler can see what your loop is doing and optimize it.

Even this is not going to be as fast as reading or mapping the source file into a buffer, then writing it back out from the same buffer with `write()`.  If all you need to do is copy the file to disk, you don’t need to copy the bytes at all.  In fact, you might even be able to make a second link to the file on disk.

This would probably work best if the slices are aligned to page boundaries.  Be very careful about having two threads write to the same cache line, as this creates a race condition.